# Hyper-V configure with internet

Tags: virtual-machine, hyper-v, internet

I am using Hyper-V to create some Windows server 2012 R2 virtual machines.  All was good until I found I could not access the internet in the virtual machine and now I am stuck.

Where I am at currently is, I created a internal virtual switch in Hyper-V and set it as my network adapter for my virtual machine.

Then I went to my network settings and I went into the properties of my WiFi connection and I went into the Share tab and I checked "Allow other network users to connect through this computer's Internet connection" and I set this to the internal hyper-v switch I created.

I tried restarting the VM, I made sure that the IPv4 will get an address automatically and I still cannot access the internet through the VM.

I wanted to check to see if I was missing a step or if my way of going about this was wrong.

Comment: I've never tired this but I'm doubtful it would work. An internal virtual switch provides connectivity between the host and the guest and doesn't proffer connectivity to the physical network. It looks like you're trying to work around that by sharing your physical network adapter with the virtual switch (essentially working in the opposite direction of the way a virtual switch typically works). I've never heard of anyone trying this before. What you probably should to do is to create an external virtual switch bound to one of the physical network adapters.

Comment: Okay, I will try that and give an update.

Comment: So after I made the change to external my VM's were able to connect to the internet.  The only question I had was after creating my domain controller, I configured the IPv4 properties of another server to point to my DC IP address.  Now this server can no longer connect to the internet.  Is there anything additional I need to configure on this server?

Comment: @joeqwerty - I recommend you add your response as an answer so that it can help other people with the same question.

Comment: @ElBe - Your second problem is better asked in a separate question. However, most likely you never set up DNS forwarders on your virtual DC.

Answer (score 0):

As Joeqwerty said in his comment, "internal" and "private" virtual switches in Hyper-V do not have any access to your local physical LAN or the internet. In order for your VMs to access the internet, they must be connected to an "external" v-switch.

An external v-switch bridges your physical network adapter to a virtual switch port that Hyper-V creates on your host. Connecting your VMs directly to an external v-switch essentially adds them to your local physical LAN the same as connecting physical computers to a physical switch on your LAN. This can have undesirable consequences, such as:

- Conflicts between lab computers and your production environment
- DNS conflicts
- DHCP scope depletion
- Lab exposure to hacking, viruses, spyware, etc. floating around your physical LAN
- Production LAN exposure to hacking, viruses, spyware, etc. being tested in your virtual LAB

In order to isolate my virtual lab from the physical environment, I set up my Hyper-V lab in this way:

1. Create an external v-Switch connected to my physical adapter.
2. Create a private v-Switch.
3. Connect all lab VMs to the private v-switch.
4. Create a tiny VM with 2 NICs and install a *nix firewall.
5. Connect the virtual firewall to both v-switches and configure NAT.

This creates a completely isolated virtual LAN in Hyper-V that's double-NATted behind the virtual firewall and your local physical LAN. I like this isolation as it allows me to mostly emulate a regular LAN environment, where my physical LAN represents the cloud.

Not every lab needs this kind of isolation, but I recommend it anyway just because it's useful. Once it's set up the first time, you can add and remove VMs to the private v-switch without needing any more network configuration.

Of course, you'll need to configure DNS, DHCP, etc. according to the needs you've identified for your lab.